Deneb vega-lite hconcat different spacing or padding between charts
If I concatenate multiple visualisations, is it possible to change the spacing between them?
For example:
"spacing": 0,
"hconcat": [
  {..}, <- chart 1
  {..}, <- chart 2
  {..}, <- chart 3
]

Is there a way to make spacing between chart 1 and chart 2 different from the spacing between chart 2 and chart 3?

Use nested hconcats and spacing. e.g.
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "Two horizonally concatenated charts that show a histogram of precipitation in Seattle and the relationship between min and max temperature.",
  "data": {"url": "data/weather.csv"},
  "transform": [{"filter": "datum.location === 'Seattle'"}],
  "spacing": 200,
  "hconcat": [
    {
      "mark": "bar",
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"timeUnit": "month", "field": "date", "type": "ordinal"},
        "y": {"aggregate": "mean", "field": "precipitation"}
      }
    },
    {
      "spacing": 50,
      "hconcat": [
        {
          "mark": "bar",
          "encoding": {
            "x": {"timeUnit": "month", "field": "date", "type": "ordinal"},
            "y": {"aggregate": "mean", "field": "precipitation"}
          }
        },
        {
          "mark": "point",
          "encoding": {
            "x": {"field": "temp_min", "bin": true},
            "y": {"field": "temp_max", "bin": true},
            "size": {"aggregate": "count"}
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}



That works and helped me find another solution which is to put "spacing": 0 before the hconcat and then  {"width": 50, "mark": "text"} between the two charts requiring 50 space between them.
